# Não consigo usar duas models em uma com cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso carregar uma Dropdown, porem os dados dessa dropdown vem de uma model e o cshtml é de outra model. Então criei uma model comum aos dois e isnerir nesse model, as duas model necessárias como property, dessa forma:
ResellerModel:

```
public class ResellerModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Alias")]
        public string Alias { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Habilitada")]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "MPN Id")]
        public string ResellerMpnId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Usar página personalizada de fechamento de pedido")]
        public bool UseCustomSuccessPage { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string CustomSuccessPage { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Google Analytics")]
        public string GA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Home Template")]
        public int HomeTemplateId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SelectListItem> HomeTemplateOptions { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Grupo de Desconto")]
        public int? AzureDiscountGroupId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AzureDiscountGroup> AzureDiscountGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

AzureDiscountGroupModel(Ainda não completa)

```
public class ResellerAzureDiscountGroupModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Grupo de Desconto")]
        public int SelectedDiscountId { get; set; }

        public List<AzureDiscountGroup> Items { get; set; }

        //public ResellerAzureDiscountGroupModel(AzureDiscountGroup group)
        //{
        //    Items = new List<AzureDiscountGroup>();
        //    Items.Add(new AzureDiscountGroup { Id = group.Id, Descricao = group.Descricao, PercDesconto = group.PercDesconto });
        //}
    }
```

E a Model Common

```
public class ResellerDiscountComomModel
    {
        public ResellerModel Reseller { get; set; }
        public ResellerAzureDiscountGroupModel ResellerAzureDiscountGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

No cshtml eu fiz assim(não vou colocar por completo, apenas alguns campos, pois todos estão da mesma forma

```
@model @model Meu_Path.API.Models.Resellers.ResellerDiscountComomModel

<h2>Editar revenda</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Reseller.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reseller.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.HomeTemplateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Reseller.HomeTemplateId, Model.Reseller.HomeTemplateOptions, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.HomeTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.Alias, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reseller.Alias, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.Alias, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.Enabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reseller.Enabled)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.Enabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.ResellerMpnId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reseller.ResellerMpnId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.ResellerMpnId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Caso não seja preenchido vai estar com o GA Default UA-79444310-1, não colocar a tag &ltscript&gt &lt/script&gt</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.GA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Reseller.GA, 11, 20, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.GA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Reseller.UseCustomSuccessPage) @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reseller.UseCustomSuccessPage)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reseller.UseCustomSuccessPage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Reseller.CustomSuccessPage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>


        <div class="edit-submit-links">
            @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Essa abordagem está me retornando esse erro:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>   'Meu_Path.API.Models.Resellers.ResellerModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type 
>   'Meu_Path.API.Models.Resellers.ResellerDiscountComomModel'.

**EDIT1**

Segue a minha controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(ResellerModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return View(model);

                var reseller = _resellerService.GetById(model.Id);

                //Verifica o Alias
                var aliasReseller = _resellerService.GetByAlias(model.Alias);

                if (aliasReseller != null && aliasReseller.Id != reseller.Id)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Alias já cadastrado para a revenda Id " + aliasReseller.Id);

                reseller.Name = model.Name;
                reseller.Alias = model.Alias;
                reseller.Enabled = model.Enabled;
                reseller.ResellerMpnId = model.ResellerMpnId;
                reseller.HomeTemplateId = model.HomeTemplateId;

                _resellerService.Update(reseller);

                var whiteLabel = _whiteLabelService.GetLastByResellerId(reseller.Id);

                whiteLabel.CustomSuccessPage = model.CustomSuccessPage;
                whiteLabel.UseCustomSuccessPage = model.UseCustomSuccessPage;

                _whiteLabelService.Update(whiteLabel);

                _genericAttributeService.SetAttributeValue(whiteLabel, "GA", model.GA);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Creio que você deverá colocar suas classes todas dentro de uma, e trabalha-las na view a partir da classe "pai".

Comment: @AugustoHenrique, tenho duas classes e ambas coloquei dentro de uma única, que é a Model Commom. É issoi que você está falando?

Comment: @AugustoHenrique, entendi agora o que vc quis dizer. Na minha Model eu tenho um `ICollection<AzureDiscountGroup>`, como carregaria isso na dropdown?

Comment: Por ViewBag seria uma boa opção, abordagem?

Comment: Como eu dou um new ResellerDiscountComomModel() de forma que as duas propriedades(classes) não fique nulas?

Comment: Voce poderia fazer uma classe pai com as outras classes filhas dentro dela. Assim você chama a classsePai.classefilha.propriedadeClasseFilha

Comment: Fiz por ViewBag e funcionou. Não gostaria, preferiria com models, mas não deu.